# Having a JavaScript error display in a div instead of an alert box

Tags: javascript, html, alert

I have this bit of javascript that will detect popup browsers disabled and the javascript is working BUT I want to have a div show the error instead of just the browser alert, but I just can't figure out why it's my `div` is not showing up. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**HTML:**

```
<span id="popupBrowserAlert" style="background-color:#ffdd77;display:none;" >Your popup blocker is enabled</span>
```

**JS:**

```
var wPopup = 'newPopup';
var popUp = window.open('page url', wPopup, 'width=800, height=600, left=24, top=24, scrollbars, resizable');



if (popUp == null || typeof(popUp) == 'undefined') {

    document.getElementById('popupBrowserAlert').style.display = 'block';
}
else {
    popUp.focus();
}
```

Comment: If a window is not opened `window.open()` returns `false` I think; test for `typeof popUp === false`. (Incidentally you can check this with `console.log(typeof popUp)`.)

Comment: @DavidThomas typeof is not a function and false is not a string bot a boolean. It should be `if(typeof popUp === false) { ... }`. Also see [this excellent post about fixing the `typeof` operator](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/fixing-the-javascript-typeof-operator/)

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen What!? [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) always returns a string, not boolean.

Comment: I tried both using `typeof popUp === false` but neither worked. I did check my `console.log(typeof popUp)` and that returned `object` though

Comment: @urbanrunic If `popUp === false` --> `typeof popUp === 'boolean'`, just follow the link in my previous comment or Robin's as well...

Comment: Ok, I read those and totally get what you are saying now. Thanks!

Comment: @Teemu David Thomas was writing: `typeof(popUp) === "false"` and `console.log(typeof(popUp))` before he edited his comment. I couldn't edit mine anymore and therefore my comment became kind of useless.

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen Well, I missed that early edition of the comment. `typeof()` can be used with parentheses as well, but it's not useful to compare the result to boolean, since `typeof` always returns a string.

Comment: Well then it seems that both @DavidThomas and I were wrong. The right use of typeof would then be `if(typeof popUp === "boolean") { ... }` or just go for the short version you wrote in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use this:

```
if (!popUp) {...}
```

This works if the value of `popUp` is `false`, `undefined`, `null`, `''` or `0`.

Comment: I like this...I'm all about simple and clean. Thank you @Teemu